# Subscribe showing deprecated

Tags: rxjs7

```
this.userService.addUser(this.user).subscribe(
  (data)=>{
    //success
    console.log(data);
    this._snack.open('Registered Successfully', 'OK', {
      duration: 2000,
      verticalPosition: 'top',
      horizontalPosition: 'center',
      panelClass: ['green-snackbar', 'login-snackbar'],
    });
  },
  (error)=>{
    //error
    console.log(error);
    this._snack.open('Something went Wrong', 'OK', {
      duration: 2000,
      verticalPosition: 'top',
      horizontalPosition: 'center',
      panelClass: ['red-snackbar','login-snackbar'],
    });
  }
);
```

I don't know what exactly is happening but subscribe showing deprecated, following is the message

```
(method) Observable<Object>.subscribe(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription (+2 overloads)
@deprecated — Instead of passing separate callback arguments, use an observer argument. Signatures taking separate callback arguments will be removed in v8. Details: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

'(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription' is deprecated.ts(6385)
Observable.d.ts(55, 9): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.
```

By the way I am using Angular13

Answer (score 14):

Just change it to:

```
this.userService.addUser(this.user).subscribe({
  next: (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    this._snack.open('Registered Successfully', 'OK', {
      duration: 2000,
      verticalPosition: 'top',
      horizontalPosition: 'center',
      panelClass: ['green-snackbar', 'login-snackbar'],
    });
  },
  error: (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    this._snack.open('Something went Wrong', 'OK', {
      duration: 2000,
      verticalPosition: 'top',
      horizontalPosition: 'center',
      panelClass: ['red-snackbar','login-snackbar'],
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What changes have you made, and what makes this work?

Comment: See that we provide an `Observer` object inside `subscribe` instead of individual callback functions separated by commas.